# Como fazer um update com um join?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, sql-update

Ola, sou novo aqui no fórum e preciso de uma ajuda com o SGBD PostgreSQL.

Minha duvida 'e o seguinte, no seguinte codigo utilizado no SGBD MySQL a execucao acontece perfeitamente, por'em no PostgreSQL mostra um erro.

Codigo MySQL:

```
 UPDATE userT
    INNER JOIN empresa ON userT.idEmp = empresa.idEmp
SET userT.telefone = '15253485',
    empresa.cargaTrab = 12
WHERE idUser = 1;
```

O código citado acima executa perfeitamente no Mysql porém no PostgreSQl aparece o seguinte erro:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "INNER".

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Isso aí não funciona no postgres

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O Postgres não suportea sintaxe ansi-92 de joins no update como o MySQL nesse sua consulta deve ser feita usando a sintaxe ansi-86 que é aquela onde a junção é feita na clásula `WHERE`

A consulta deve ficar assim:

```
 UPDATE userT SET
    userT.telefone = '15253485',
    empresa.cargaTrab = 12
 FROM empresa
    WHERE userT.idEmp = empresa.idEmp
    AND idUser = 1;
```

Comment: Oi, tudo joia? Quero atualizar tanto o telefone da tabela userT quanto cargaTrab da tabela empresa, assim apenas tem comparacao da carga trabalhada com idUser.

Comment: @AndréFrança edite a respostas veja se é isso.

Comment: E se eu quiser pegar os dados que vão ser inseridos (mais de um campo) de outra tabela?

Answer (score 5):

```
with t as (
  -- Any generic query which returns rowid and corresponding calculated values
  select t1.id as rowid, f(t2, t2) as calculatedvalue
  from table1 as t1
  join table2 as t2 on t2.referenceid = t1.id
)
update t1
set value = t.calculatedvalue
from t
where id = t.rowid
```

Comment: se vc puder [edit] e além do código dar uma explicaçãozinha, valoriza um bocado seu post

Comment: A utilização do termo `WITH` é perfeita para fazer o `UPDATE` no qual é preciso fazer `JOIN` com várias tabelas.

Answer (score 2):

Faço da seguinte forma via select com a condição que preciso.

```
update ESTOQUE
set QTDE=100
where CODMARCA in (select CODIGO from marca where nome = CONDIÇÃO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá 
eu sempre faço da seguinte forma, monto o `sql` para instrução select
Exemplo:

```
SELECT
       c.nome,
       tc.descricao
from cliente c 
left join tipo_cliente tc on tc.id_tipo_cliente  = c.id_tipo_cliente
    where
tc.id_tipo_cliente=13;
```

---

> **Aviso**: A operação a seguir não é suportada PostgreSQL([Update Syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-update.html))

Com base no select gero o update:

```
update cliente c
    left join tipo_cliente tc on tc.id_tipo_cliente  = c.id_tipo_cliente
set tc.descricao='TESTE'
where tc.id_tipo_cliente=13;
```

Com o select feito e funcionando, copia e apaga as informações do select do from para traz.
Adiciona update e após os `joins` e antes do `where` o `set`.

Comment: No PostgreSQL que é o objeto dessa pergunta seu código de `UPDATE` dá o seguinte erro: `Query Error: error: syntax error at or near "left"` isso porque o PostgreSQL não suporta  `join` dentro de update.