# Update a partir da comparação entre duas tabelas postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Tenho uma tabela vendas que contém o código do vendedor.

Porém a tabela de vendedor foi toda refeita, com a alteração do `id`.

Como posso atualizar o código de vendedor na tabela vendas a partir da comparação entre a nova tabela vendedor e a antiga?

Tentei fazendo `join` porém foi feito `update` com o mesmo `id` de vendedor  para todos os registros da tabela `vendas`.

Comment: [Como fazer um update com um join?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120076/91)

Comment: A primeira coisa que você tem que fazer é definir como saber que dois registros, um da tabela antiga e outro da tabela nova, se referem ao mesmo vendedor. Tendo definido esta correspondência é só atualizar a tabela vendas, por exemplo com o resultado da junção das tabelas nova e antiga de vendedor. Pelo que você descreve do resultado muito provavelmente sua cláusula WHERE está errada.

Comment: Presumindo que o id da tabela vendedor seja a chave primária desta tabela e que tal campo era utilizado como chave estrangeira na tabela vendas, qual a maneira que você considera que possa associar o id antigo com o novo id?
Quais são as definições de suas tabelas e particularmente a definição das chaves estrangeiras.

Comment: O que é possível comparar nas tabelas para definir a associação entre o id antigo e o novo gerado quando você refez a tabela vendedor? Espero que você tenha um backup de seu banco na posição anterior à ação de refazer a tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Para ser usado `JOIN` você deve ter um relacionamento entre as tabelas, do contrário não conseguirá, veja como poderá ser feito:

```
UPDATE Vendas set camposVendas = novoValor,... JOIN TabelaVendedor1 as TB1 ON TB1.campoVerifica = campoTabelaVenda ou TB2 JOIN TabelaVendedor2 as TB2 ON TB2.campoVerificad = campoTabelaVenda ou TB1
```

Lembre-se, deve haver relacionamento entre essas tabelas para essa instrução funcionar.
Espero ter Ajudado!

Comment: A maneira de se fazer um JOIN em um comando `UPDATE` no PostgreSQL é utilizar a cláusula `FROM` e não a cláusula `JOIN`. Consulte a documentação.

Comment: E o perguntador some ...