# Como usar join em UPDATE?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Esse é meu comando:

```
UPDATE address SET lat = :latitude, lng = :longitude WHERE menu_id = :menu
```

Só que `menu_id` não é da mesma tabela.

Como posso fazer?

Comment: seu banco de dados é mysql?

Comment: Em qual banco de dados? a sintaxe pode variar de um para outro.

Comment: Nao, meu banco de dados é o postgres

Comment: [Como fazer um update com um join?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120076/91)

Comment: O dado que tenho em comum entre a tabela menu e a tabela address é o campo address_id